# How to display joined and repeated data in nested datarepeaters?

Tags: c#, repeater

I want to display an interrelated data in nested data repeaters, but when I do this by drag and drop, only first level data repeater works, remaining doesn't show anything.

Is there any idea how to do this?
Here is an example what I want to display:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the eventhandler "onitemdatabound" on the outer to fill the inner Repeater everytime. Here and short example:

In the .aspx File:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater_Parent" runat="server" onitemdatabound="Repeater_Parent_ItemDataBound">
    <!-- //Show data for the Repeater_Parent -->
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater_Child" runat="server">
        <!-- //Show data for the Repeater_Child -->
    </asp:Repeater> 
</asp:Repeater>
```

In the .cs File:

```
 protected void Repeater_Parent_ItemDataBound(object source, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) {
    //Saves the repeater_parent as repeaterSource
    RepeaterItem repeaterSource = e.Item;
    //Find the chhild Repeater
    Repeater childRepeater = repeaterSource.FindControl("Repeater_Child") as Repeater;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    //Here fill the ds with some kind of data you want to display in the child Repeater

    //Bind ds to Child repeater
    childRepeater.DataSource = ds;
    childRepeater.DataBind();
}
```